# JMeter5-5 Perfomance Test with Joomla

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, joomla

Halo, anyone know how to test login page using joomla ?
i already tried to follow tutorial how to PT Jmeter for login page, overall need to define the parameter or using record in jmeter.

i tried to get the parameter, but in joomla the parameter body is different with the tutorial.
and using recording too it succes when record only. but when i tried start in jmeter it will failed when try to hit the post method.

in tutorial parameter request is something like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6s2f.png
source:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGkrSFKcj10&t=242s

but in my website is like thishttps://i.stack.imgur.com/tG3QH.png

is there anyone have some solution for this ? or have any experience PT for joomla ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot successfully replay the recorded script because this `authenticity_token` parameter is **dynamic**

[image]

so need to build your test plan as follows:

1. Open login page
2. Extract this `authenticity_token` using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
3. In the login POST request replace the recorded hard-coded value with the JMeter Variable from step 2

The process is known as [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter) and there is a lot of information on handling it in JMeter over the Internet so I would recommend doing a research on "Correlation in JMeter" instead of trying to exactly follow steps from 6-years-old-video

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thank you for reply.
but for that screenshot is succes to replay. you can refer to the source youtube.
my problem at the picture 2 > https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG3QH.png

there no have any token in post parameter.
and my company using joomla to login page

Comment: "there no have any token in post parameter" because you're not looking into "post parameters", you're looking at response [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers). If you cannot or unwilling to perform correlation manually you can consider using [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder) for capturing the test flow, it automatically detects and handles dynamic parameters so you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: this a full inspection page, i dont know when i tried to follow tutorial they have like "authenticity_token" but in my company browser they dont have any something like that. this screenshot for the inspection page> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U6N11Q2_EiSIcX_5s4LKENC4ghh4mR70/view?usp=sharing

okei, i try using blazemeter.
i dont know that will work or not the blazemeter extension only in chrome
but my company website only can be access from firefox.
thank you dmitri ~

Comment: i tried to using blazemeter proxy recored.
but i dont why blazemeter can't record live production wesbite, and when i hit the development website they only record this 
[ 15:16:58 ]
GET
http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt?ipv4
[ 15:16:58 ]
GET
http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt?ipv6
[ 15:16:57 ]
GET
http://detectportal.firefox.com/canonical.html

and the website only loading, did not go to the login page. something like lose connection only for link development.